If $X/A$ is a hausdorff space, proof that $A$ is closed in $X$
Let $X$ be a topologic space and  $A \subset X$ a not-empty subset. We note with $X/A$ the quotient space of  $X/ \sim$ where $\forall x,y \in X: x \sim y \iff (x = y $ or $x,y \in A)$. The topology on $X/A$ is de quotient topology induced by the natural map $p: X \to X/A$.
assume now  $X$ to be compact and a hausdorffspace.
I have to prove that $X/A$ is a hausdorff space if and only if $A$ is closed.
I came so far up with the following proof:
Proof:
Direction $\implies $:  Assume $X/A$ is a hausdorff space. Choose now $z \in X \backslash A := A^c $ arbitrarily in $X$ and look at $p(z) = zA \neq A$ in $ X/A$. Because $X/A$ was a hausdorff space, we know that for all $zA \in (X/A)\backslash A := A^c$ in $X/A$ must exist an open $U_{zA} \in T_{quotient}$ around $zA$  such that $U_{zA} \subset A^c$ in $X/A$ and thus we find that $A^c$ is open in $X/A$. Because  $p$ is now a quotienten map,  $p^{-1}(A^c) = \{x \in X | xA \neq A\} = \{x \in X | x \notin A\} = A^c$ in $X$ is open thus  is $A$ closed in $X$.  $\blacksquare$
Can anyone help me with my proof? I m not sure if it is rigorously enough. further I didn't even use the fact that $X$ was compact or Hausdorff and I wonder if I made a mistake. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

At the second sentence of the proof, what has $z$ to do with $x$?

Thank you. My mistake

Why don't you just say that, since $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff and ${A}\in X/\sim$, then ${{A}}$ is a closed subset of $X/\sim$ and that therefore, since $A=p^{-1}({{A}})$, $A$ is a closed subset of $X/\sim$?

Thank you for your correction. This is much better and more elegant. ^^
